# How to retrieve the latest created record using loopback api and angularjs

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, loopbackjs, strongloop

Below is my Modal controller.
Se_chnl and Se_segn_rqst are the Loopback models.
I'm initializing the modal form in the first step.
The $scope.Se_chnl_find() is getting me a list from the backend which I load as a dropdown menu in the modal.
This call to loopback works fine.

Then later on once the form is filled, I call the submit function and in that I call the create function of loopback Se_segn_rqst.create($scope.rqst)
$scope.rqst contains the parameters for creating that rqst.

Now, once I have created this "rqst", I want to retrieve ID of the latest created request by that user and store it in the global variable.
But the loopback api/MySQL doesn't return anything.
Record is created in the backend when create is used.
But the find function doesn't work.

I tried the find filter in Strongloop/Loopback explorer and it works there.
Not sure why it is not returning anything when I tried it from the controller.

```
    codeApp.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function($scope, $modalInstance, $state, Se_chnl, Se_segn_rqst) {

    var defaultForm = {
        cmpgn_nm: "",
        cmpgn_id: "",
        strgy_id: "",
        rqst_typ_cd: "",
        chnl_id: ""
    }
    $scope.channels = Se_chnl.find({
        filter: {
            "fields": {
                "chnl_nm": true,
                "chnl_id": true
            }
        }
    });

    $scope.rqst = angular.copy(defaultForm);

    $scope.rqst.rqst_id = 0;

    $scope.submit = function(reqForm) {

        $scope.rqst.rqst_nm = $scope.rqst.cmpgn_nm;
        $scope.rqst.rqst_stat_cd = 'DRAFT';
        $scope.rqst.insrt_user_id = $scope.$parent.user_id;
        $scope.rqst.insrt_dt = new Date();



        Se_segn_rqst.create($scope.rqst);

        $scope.$parent.requested_id = Se_segn_rqst.find({
            filter: {
                "fields": {
                    "rqst_id": true
                },
                "order": "insrt_dt DESC",
                "limit": 1,
                "where": {
                    "rqst_stat_cd": "DRAFT",
                    "insrt_user_id": "xyz123"
                }
            }
        });

        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');

    };

    $scope.resetForm = function(reqForm) {
        $scope.rqst = angular.copy(defaultForm);
        reqForm.$setPristine();
        reqForm.$setUntouched();
    };
});
```

This is the piece returning no value. I want an id in the requested_id global variable. The filter is performing correctly in the Strongloop explorer, so there is no syntax error.

```
$scope.$parent.requested_id = Se_segn_rqst.find({
            filter: {
                "fields": {
                    "rqst_id": true
                },
                "order": "insrt_dt DESC",
                "limit": 1,
                "where": {
                    "rqst_stat_cd": "DRAFT",
                    "insrt_user_id": "xyz123"
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Question has been answered on this google group [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/loopbackjs/qdPaorTpOAA)

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit more information needed, but we can discuss the rest here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/loopbackjs/qdPaorTpOAA